# Error: 'index.html' could not be found

Tags: django, django-templates

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.techiediaries.com/django-angular-cli/).

I get this error when I run the server-

```
 Page not found (404)
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    Raised by:  django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve
    'index.html' could not be found
```

[image]
[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: A little bit more details would be helpful regarding the project to pinpoint the error. Though why is `index.html` being referenced? could that be an error?

Comment: Post full traceback.

Comment: @xyres posted in the ques

Comment: Is your `index.html` file in the `static` directory?

Comment: Yes, it is in the static directory

Comment: That is a *very* odd tutorial. There's no good reason for serving the index page as a static file, it defeats the whole purpose of using Django. Yes, the *Angular* templates are static files, but the home page needs to be dynamic.